# Install shield undo never show dialog

Tags: installshield

I checked a "Never show dialog" Checkbox in Install Shield.

How can I reset this?

I suspect a registry key but have been unable to locate the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The setting should be available in `Tools > Options`, but as you suspect it's also stored in the registry. Try looking for values under `HKCU\Software\InstallShield\##.#\Professional.